# Exibir div de acordo com o dia e a hora

Tags: php

Estou montando um sistema (meio que emergencial) para a igreja, para transmissão ao vivo, por causa do isolamento social. Na Página onde estou incorporando a live, no site da igreja, quero que, se a pessoa entrar dentro do dia e horário oficial de culto, e o vídeo não começar, apareça para ele uma `div` com um **"clique aqui"** para dar um restart na página.

Se for outros dias e horários, onde não tiver ao vivo, que apareça outra `div`, com um **"clique aqui"** para ir para a página de cultos gravados.

Então, em resumo, quando a pessoa entrar, o php vai pegar  dia e a hora, e conferir com os dias e horários das variáveis. Se bater com algum, aparece a `div 1`, se não bater, aparece a `div 2`.

A ideia eu tenho, mas quero correr enquanto mal consigo engatinhar, aí ficou difícil. Eis o código que pensei, mas que não funcionou:

```
<?php
$dataatual = ('w');
$horaatual = ('H:i:s');
$horade    = '19:59:59';
$horaate   = '21:00:01';
$horade1   = '08:59:59';
$horaate1  = '10:00:01';
$horade2   = '19:29:59';
$domingo   = '0';
$quarta    = '3';
$quinta    = '4';

if (($dataatual = $domingo and ($horaatual >= $horade1 and $horaatual <= $horaate1))) or (($dataatual = $domingo and ($horaatual >= $horade2 and $horaatual <= $horaate))) or (($dataatual = $quarta and $horaatual >= $horade and $horaatual <= $horaate))) or (($dataatual = $quinta and $horaatual >= $horade and $horaatual <= $horaate))) { ?>
<div class="conteudo">

<h3>Olá, estamos ao vivo. Caso não esteja visualizando o vídeo, Clique <a href="https://www.ibnagv.com.br/cultos-ao-vivo/">AQUI </a>para atualizar sua página.</h3>
  </div><?php } ?>

else { ?>

<div class="conteudo1">
<h3>Olá, no momento não estamos ao vivo. Mas você pode assistir nossos cultos gravados, clicando <a href="https://www.ibnagv.com.br/cultos-gravados/">AQUI </a>ou acessando o Menu Mídias / Cultos Gravados. Obrigado. </h3></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existia dois problemas, o primeiro era nas variáveis de $dataatual e $horaatual que estavam sem a função date, o segundo era no IF que estava sendo fechado antes das outras condicionais, ocasionando um erro de sintaxe.

Dei uma ajustada no código e ficou assim:

```
$dataatual = date('w');
$horaatual = date('H:i:s');
$horade    = '19:59:59';
$horaate   = '21:00:01';
$horade1   = '08:59:59';
$horaate1  = '10:00:01';
$horade2   = '19:29:59';

$domingo   = '0';
$quarta    = '3';
$quinta    = '4';

if (($dataatual = $domingo and ($horaatual >= $horade1 and $horaatual <= $horaate1))
or (($dataatual = $domingo and ($horaatual >= $horade2 and $horaatual <= $horaate)))
or (($dataatual = $quarta and $horaatual >= $horade and $horaatual <= $horaate))
or (($dataatual = $quinta and $horaatual >= $horade and $horaatual <= $horaate))){ 
 echo '<div class="conteudo">
<h3>Olá, estamos ao vivo. Caso não esteja visualizando o vídeo, Clique 
<a href="https://www.ibnagv.com.br/cultos-ao-vivo/">AQUI </a>para atualizar sua página.</h3></div>'; 
} else { 
echo '<div class="conteudo1"> <h3>Olá, no momento não estamos ao vivo. Mas você pode assistir nossos cultos gravados, clicando <a href="https://www.ibnagv.com.br/cultos-gravados/">AQUI </a>ou acessando o Menu Mídias / Cultos Gravados. Obrigado. </h3></div>';

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!

Comment: se tiver como marcar a resposta como correta ficaria grato :)

Answer (score 0):

fiz umas alterações, espero ter sido útil de alguma forma, pelo menos te deixa um poucos mais confortável, para editar o código futuramente.

teste em
[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nvrr-74b8)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$dataatual  =   date('w');      ##PEGA O DIA ATUAL PARA VERIFICAÇÃO;
$horaatual  =   date('H:i:s');  ##PEGA A HORA ATUAL PARA VERIFICAÇÃO;

##CRIA UMA LISTAGEM DE TODOS OS DIAS E TODOS OS HORÁRIOS DE CADA DIA;
$diasON =   array(
    '0'   =>  array(
                        ['inicio' => '08:59:59', 'fim' => '10:00:01'],
                        ['inicio' => '19:29:59', 'fim' => '21:00:01'],
                    ),
    '3'    =>  array(
                        ['inicio' => '19:59:59', 'fim' => '21:00:01'],
                    ),
    '4'    =>  array(
                        ['inicio' => '19:59:59', 'fim' => '21:00:01'],
                    )
);

?>

<html>
<head>
<!-- SCRIPTS/CSS -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron mt-3">
        <?php
        ##VERIFICA O DIA ATUAL SE EXISTE TRANSMISSÃO AO VIVO;
        if(isset($diasON[$dataatual])) {

            foreach($diasON[$dataatual] as $horarios) {
                if($horaatual >= $horarios['inicio'] AND $horaatual <= $horarios['fim']) {
                    ##VERIFICA SE JÁ ESTÁ TRANSMITINDO;
                    echo    '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                <h2>Estamos [Ao Vivo]. Clique <a href="https://www.ibnagv.com.br/cultos-ao-vivo/">AQUI </a>para abrir o vídeo.</h2>
                            </div>';

                } elseif($horaatual <= $horarios['inicio']) {
                    ##AVISA O HORÁRIO QUE VAI COMEÇAR;
                    echo    '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                <h2>Próximo culto ao vivo: <b>' . $horarios['inicio'] . '</b> até <b>' . $horarios['fim'] . '</b></h2>
                            </div>';

                } elseif($horaatual >= $horarios['fim']) {
                    ##AVISA QUE JA ENCERROU A TRANSMISSÃO;
                    echo    '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                <h2>A transmissão de <b>' . $horarios['inicio'] . '</b> foi encerrada: <b>' . $horarios['fim'] . '</b></h2>
                            </div>';
                } 
            }

        } else {
            echo '<h4>Olá, hoje não teremos programação ao vivo. Mas você pode assistir nossos cultos gravados, clicando <a href="https://www.ibnagv.com.br/cultos-gravados/">AQUI </a>ou acessando o Menu Mídias / Cultos Gravados. Obrigado. </h4>';
        }
        ?>        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</htm>
```